# jQuery delegated .off() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function (stripped down for simplicity's sake):

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-trigger', function() {
  console.log('click enabled');
});
```

so when i click on `.js-trigger` i get the console.log message, all fine so far. Then as soon as i resize the window, it should stop executing this function. i tried the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(document).off('click', '.js-trigger');    
});
```

Then when i click on `.js-trigger` it should no longer output the console.log message but it still does! I have tried many different variations but the `off()` event never seems to successfully happen... What am i doing wrong?

Interestingly, if i change it to this:

```
$('.js-trigger').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click enabled');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.js-trigger').off();    
});
```

it works as expected but i need the events to be delegated cause sometimes `.js-trigger` is not present in the DOM on page load...

Comment: Use `one()` instead?

Comment: Unable to replicate the problem, your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5mvhpdx9/

Comment: @Nope Then it only fires once, i need it to fire every concurrent time...

Comment: I see, in that case, would a named function not work? `$(document).on('click', '.js-trigger', myfunction` and then later `$(document).off('click', myfunction)`

Comment: Afaik you still need to pass the same selector to `off`. But as mentioned above, code in the question already works...

Comment: As Rory says above, your issue can't be replicated. It's usually a good idea to post a complete piece of code which shows your problem, not just snippets you've tried. The problem must be in the way you combined those snippets.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your fiddle indeed works but even if i literally copy everything you did into my project, it somehow doesn't work anymore. Looking into external factors (jQuery version, maybe minification is screwing it up) now...

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? It would help to see a more complete sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to modify your delegate event listener to have an extra condition on the child selector.

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-trigger:not(.ignore)', function() {
  console.log('click enabled');
});
```

Then for those you don't want the logic to happen to, you add the ignore class.  Or whatever conditional logic you choose.

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up using this technique, made some other parts of my code a bit simpler too :) @Taplar